# Quantizing the size of a pro-$p$ group

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, profinite-groups

Let $p$ be a prime number and $G$ be a pro-$p$ group (not necessarily powerful). Let $\Omega$ denote the completed group algebra $\mathbb{F}_p[[G]]:=\varprojlim_N \mathbb{F}_p[G/N]$, where $N$ ranges over all open normal subgroups. Let $I$ be the augmentation ideal in $\Omega$, i.e., the kernel of the map $\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p$ sending each group like element to $1$. Set $c_n$ to denote the dimension of $\Omega/I^n$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Let $H(t):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n t^n$ denote the Hilbert series, we note that the radius of convergence for $H(t)$ is $1/r_G$, where $r_G:=\limsup_n |c_n|^{1/n}$.

I'd like to think of $r_G$ as somehow measuring the "size" of the pro-$p$ group. When $G$ is analytic pro-$p$, then $r_G=1$. However, when this is not the case, then $r_G$ can be $>1$. The reason I'm interested in this quantity $r_G$ is that the proof of Vinberg's refinement of the Golod-Shafarevich criterion shows that if the Golod-Shafarevich polynomial takes a negative value at $t_0\in (0,1)$, then, not only is $G$ infinite, but in fact, $r_G\geq 1/t_0$. This sort of criterion is used a lot in number theory, for instance, in constructing infinite Hilbert class field towers, and obtaining new records for Martinet constants (i.e., root discriminant bounds). Therefore, I'd like to think of this as somehow saying that the closer $t_0$ is to $0$, the larger the value of $r_G$ and hence the "larger" $G$ is. Thus, the refined Golod-Shafarevich criterion not only tells us if the group is infinite but gives us a measure for how large the group is. Thus the series $H(t)$ is analogous to the Hilbert polynomial in algebraic geometry, which gives one information about what the dimension of a variety is. Of course, I understand that if $r_G>1$, then $c_n$ cannot be polynomial in $n$, however, must be growing at a faster rate.

I'd like to know if the quantity $r_G$ is studied in the literature and if there is any standard terminology for it as somehow measuring the size of $G$. I'd also like to know how well behaved it is. For instance, I'd expect that if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of finite index, then, $r_H=r_G$. If $H$ is any closed normal subgroup then, $r_H\leq r_G$. In this case is $r_Hr_{G/H}=r_G$? I'm not able to prove such properties, have they been studied and listed anywhere?

Comment: About notation: do you know about Interlude D in the book "Analytic Pro-p Groups"? Your $r_G$ is denoted by $\rho(\boldsymbol{c})$ there. It is the only place I know where your $r_G$ is mentioned. But there might be more...